# PHP- One php page will receive GET data in 4 second interval and another page will display the updated data by refreshing itself

Tags: php

The question is one page will receive the GET data in 4 second interval and i have to display the parameter value in another page with updated value.It is just for display and no need to store the value.

I have tried it with the following code:
datareceiver.php

```
<?php
    require 'localStore.php';
    if(isset($_REQUEST['name'])){
        localStore::setData($_REQUEST['name']);
    }
?>
```

localStore.php

```
<?php
    class localStore{
       private static $dataVal = "";
       public static function setData($data){
          self::$dataVal = $data;
       }
       public static function getData(){
          return self::$dataVal;
       }
    }
?>
```

display.php

```
<?php
    require 'localStore.php';
    header("Refresh:2");
    echo localStore::getData();
?>
```

How i can show the data in 'display.php' page, because the above 'display.php' prints blank on the page. I tried also the global keyword concept and the PHP magic _construct(), _get() and _set() by searching in google and going through stackoverflow. but it was difficult to understand since i am not a PHP guy. t was terrible for me to use these _get(),_set() and _construct().

Comment: PHP doesn't work like this. You have to store your data somewhere anyway.

Answer (score 0):

PHP doesn't work like this. You have to store your data somewhere anyway. Script2 knows nothing about data recieved by script1. When you construct your localStore object it doesn't have access to properties of another object constructed by another execution, cause your datareciever object was destructed immediately after script end. You can check it usind __destruct() method

So, you need some storage to keep recieved by script1 data until script2 wants to display it. Most commonly used ways are: mysql DB, file and queue, say Rabbit.

The simpliest solution is

```
   const FILE_NAME = 'tmp/anyname';
   public static function setData($data){
      return file_put_contents(self::FILE_NAME, serialize($data));
   }
   public static function getData(){
      $str = file_get_contents(self::FILE_NAME);
      return unserialize($str);
   }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply. But is it possible the data will receive and show immediately?

Comment: @Behera Can you fill and pour out same bottle at the same time?